# return из _.forEach() в lodash выводит весь массив

Tags: javascript, lodash

вот сам код:

```
findElem(filters, curFilter) 
{
    console.log("filters", filters)
    let result = forEach(filters, function(value) {
        try {
            if ( value.id == curFilter ) {
                return value;
            } else {
                this.findElem(value.categories)
            }
        } catch (e) {}
    });
    console.log("result", result);
}
```

по идее `return value;` должен вызваться один раз и выбросить из перебора, в остальных случаях просто начинать перебор с начала, но с другими параметрами. В итоге он выводит мне массив `filters` тот, который я вводил в `forEach` при первом вызове. Что я сделал не так? Как вывести только один объект value?

Comment: в справке к [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach) прямо указывается, что возвращается переданная коллекция. Если ты хочешь _найти_ элемент, то нужно использовать другие функции, Например [find](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

Comment: @Grundy документацию невнимательно прочитал, виноват. Решил проблему созданием внешней переменной и записью результата перебора туда